# How to set the style of a cell in asp:DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net

How can i set the (css) style of a cell in an `asp:DataGrid`?

---

What am i really trying to achieve? An `html` `table`, where i control the per-cell html content, and the per-row and per-cell css style:

```
<TABLE>
   <TR class="odd available">
      <TD class="holiday available hassub firstColumn">
          <P ...>...
      <TD class="blackout">
          <A href="...">...</A>
      <TD style="available">
          <SPAN ...>...</SPAN>
      <TD class="booked">
          <DIV ...>...</DIV>
      <TD class="orphan available">
          <DIV ...>...</DIV>
      <TD style="orphan booked checked">
          <SPAN ...>...</SPAN>
          <A href="...">...</A>
          <DIV ...>...</DIV>
   </TR>
   <TR class="blackout">
      <TD>34 points
      <TD><%# GetHtmlForCell() %>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
```

And it is accepted that [an `asp:Repeater` cannot work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361729/create-a-html-table-with-an-asp-repeater) in this case.

i have HTML that i need to generate; and i just have to see if ASP.net can generate required html. i'm guessing not, since "WebForms" means you don't generate HTML.

### Bonus Chatter

An `asp:DataGrid` control in ASP.net renders multiple cells. The formatting of each style can be adjusted by [setting various formatting properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx), for example:

- [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.backcolor.aspx)
- [`ForeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.forecolor.aspx)
- [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.font.aspx)

But there is no way to adjust the `Style` of a cell, e.g.

```
style="holiday blackout hassub"
```

### Bonus Reading

Some unrelated bonus reading:

- [Change the style of cell within datagrid](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/42372.aspx/1)
- [MSDN: DataGridViewCellStyle Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx)
- How to set the style of a cell in an asp:ListView?
- [Create a HTML table with an ASP repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361729/create-a-html-table-with-an-asp-repeater)
- [How to create a three column table in ASP.Net Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442897/how-to-create-a-three-column-table-in-asp-net-repeater)
- [custom html code in a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366762/html-table-layout-when-binding-with-asp-net-c-sharp-repeater)
- [MSDN: Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx)

Comment: Are you actually refering to the old `DataGrid` control instead of the `GridView`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do :( you're setting css classes using style attribute. Is it a typo?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Yes, my mistake. It's 78° in here; my brain is fried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you actually mean a `GridView` instead of the old `DataGrid`, you can use the [`CssClass` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) for the `GridViewRow` and `TableCells`.

For example in [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx):

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = "odd available";
            e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "holiday available hassub firstColumn";
            // ....
            e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "orphan booked checked";
        }
        else if(e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
            e.Row.CssClass = "blackout";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done if you handle the OnRowDataBound. Example:

```
<style>
.class25
{
    background-color:Red;  
}
.class25a
{
    font-weight:bolder;
}
.class23
{
    background-color:Yellow;  
}
.class23a
{
    font-size:20px;
}
.class33
{
    background-color:Fuchsia;  
}
.class33a
{
    font-style:italic;
}
</style>
<asp:GridView ID="customGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="customGrid_RowDataBound">
```

Now on Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

private void BindData()
{
    List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>(){
        new Employee{Age=25,ID=1,First="John",Last="Smith"},
        new Employee{Age=23,ID=2,First="Juan",Last="Cabrera"},
        new Employee{Age=33,ID=3,First="Richard",Last="Mar"}
    };

    customGrid.DataSource = emp;
    customGrid.DataBind();

}

protected void customGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.DataItem as Employee).Age == 25)
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "class25 class25a");
        else if((e.Row.DataItem as Employee).Age == 23)
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "class23 class23a");
        else
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "class33 class33a");
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

Renders:

[image]