# How to add class to td in asp datagrid table

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I've got an asp `ASP:DataGrid`, and within this 5 columns. Now i could use pure CSS such as `:nth-child` but for maximum comparability I'd love to just slot a class onto the 5th td in the row server-side so that i am not relying on Javascript to save me.

Can this be done? I know you can add a class to the table row via `HeaderStyle-CssClass="foo"`

Comment: You shouldn't put asp.net mvc into your tags if your question is connected to asp.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the style of a cell in asp:DataGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586854/how-to-set-the-style-of-a-cell-in-aspdatagrid)

Comment: Not a duplicate question as i am using Datagrids, whereas i believe the answer accepts in the other question is for GridViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for anyone who this might help. Due to not being in control of the bulk of the code i couldn't implement a gridview so i had to work with the datagrid.

In order to apply a class to a `td` in the table, you can do the follow:

```
ItemStyle-CssClass="foo"
```

On the TemplateColumn, like so:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="foo" HeaderText="Header Text">
```